# Shared com port in asp.net application

Tags: c#, serial-port, port, shared

I wonder if any of you have faced the same problem or may be there is a solution for this subject:

I have a hardware system that consist of 2 closed-loop pipe-lines with pumps and flowmeters installed. The flowmeters connected to com ports of pc. There are two applications that intended to read data from these com ports:

- Data acquisition system (asp.net wab app) reads data every 500ms
- Monitoring and flowmeters management system (asp.net wab app) reads data every 60s and writes data to flowmeters from time to time.

The problems are:
1. how to share com ports between the applications.
2. How to avoid conflicts of common access?

My option is to create an object that holds the com ports communication information (address, name, parity...) and this object is available for both applications lifetime. And the applications uses this object to read and write data to flowmeters. The only problem that I have faced in the option, is the common access chance.

Any architectural guidance is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: There is a very strong potential that the two apps will clash over the com ports, one complaining that it is in use by the other app..unless you put in some sort of schedule in place to open the port, read, close, let the other app open the port, read, close, at intervals.

Comment: There are hardware solutions for this. We use [Digi Servers](http://www.digi.com/products/serial-servers/serial-device-servers/portserverts). But we only read from the port, so I can't tell you how writing works.